# jQuery fadeIn() different intervals with multiple div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I have a homepage with six div's. They are different shaped boxes, and I want them to fade in at random intervals when the page loads. The javascript code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#topleft").fadeIn(2000).animate({opacity: 1.0});
});
```

Of course, I need all six div's to be targeted, not just one, and I want them to randomly fade in within about 3 seconds of the page load. How would I go about this? By the way, I am using jQuery and since I'm new at it, there may be something I could use that I don't know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/gTFsk/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine. Just a quick question, though. Is there a way to slow down the speed of the random fading? In other words, the divs fade in almost all at once. Can I make it delay after each div (1 second or so), before it fades the next?

Comment: @Glen I made the change for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/gTFsk/ I used a weird trick inserting empty divs to hold the place of the divs until they start to fade in, at which point the divs are removed.

Comment: Actually I just realized you want them to basically come one at a time. I'll make another change and you can compare the two.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I'm looking for. The only problem, is that it is a little choppy. They load, then shift or change position but end up where they need to be. Is there any way to eliminate that?

Comment: @Glen hmm... I used empty divs as placeholders to prevent that but maybe it doesn't work in all browsers. Which browser did you try it in?

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, the reason they look choppy, is that I am floating them left, so that if one div is not there another takes its place but then moves over when the real div appears. Could I make it so that all of the div's are fixed in a position so that they don't take each other's place? Like, instead of display:none, somehow make them invisible, but they are there.

Comment: @Glen, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/G4pxq/3/ I changed it so that the invisible placeholder divs have `display: block`, and `visibility: hidden` with exactly the same contents as the original div. Let me know if that works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

What you'll probably want to do is have all six divs have a similar class, so that you can target them all at once.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/hadbz/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine. Just a quick question, though. Is there a way to slow down the speed of the random fading? In other words, the divs fade in almost all at once. Can I make it delay after each div (1 second or so), before it fades the next?

Comment: Yes, if I am understanding what you are asking. What you want is to have div 1 fadeIn and finish, then div 2 fadeIn and finish, etc., correct? If so check this example out: http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/3DE6v/.

Comment: Right, but just as I was saying to PaulPRO, Text1 slides down when text2 appear, then it slides again when text3 appears. Could you make text one appear in its final position only(three lines down from the top), so it would not continue to bump down?

Comment: Is http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/dc3TA/ what you're looking for? The element remains in its final position without sliding up or down.

Answer (score 0):

Create all divs with the same class like alldivs then:

```
$('.alldivs').each(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random()*3000)).animate({opacity: 1.0});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine. Just a quick question, though. Is there a way to slow down the speed of the random fading? In other words, the divs fade in almost all at once. Can I make it delay after each div (1 second or so), before it fades the next?

Comment: sure, just do: 
$('.alldivs').each(function(**count=0**) {

    $(this).fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random()*3000 **+ (count * 1000)** ).animate({opacity: 1.0});

    **count++;**

});

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomFromTo(from, to){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
$('.six_div').each(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
    }, randomFromTo(100,3000));
});
```

NOTE: the 'six_div' class will need to be added to each of the six divs so they will all be selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine. Just a quick question, though. Is there a way to slow down the speed of the random fading? In other words, the divs fade in almost all at once. Can I make it delay after each div (1 second or so), before it fades the next?