# jQuery fadeIn() intervals multiple div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I'm following the indications on the post:
[jQuery fadeIn() different intervals with multiple div's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769895/jquery-fadein-different-intervals-with-multiple-divs)

but i just cant get it to work.. what is wrong

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.fadeIn').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.before('<div>&nbsp;</div>');
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $this.prev().remove(); 
            $this.fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random()*1500)); 
        }, Math.floor(Math.random()*1500));
    }
);​

</script>       

<style>

.fadeIn{
   display: none; 
}​
​
</style>

</head>



<body>

<div class="fadeIn">Test 1</div>
<div class="fadeIn">Test 2</div>
<div class="fadeIn">Test 3</div>
<div class="fadeIn">Test 4</div>
<div class="fadeIn">Test 5</div>
<div class="fadeIn">Test 6</div>​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to include the jQuery library

Comment: And you need to wrap your code in a `$(function() { })` statement to ensure the DOM is ready before it executes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo in action](http://jsbin.com/adefez/edit#javascript,html,live)

You have to import the jQuery library!
Add it Before your `<script>`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it should look like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($){ // remap the '$' character to jQuery

$('.fadeIn').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.before('<div>&nbsp;</div>');
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $this.prev().remove(); 
            $this.fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random()*1500)); 
        }, Math.floor(Math.random()*1500));
)};

})(jQuery);


</script>
```

Or use the `$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code here*/ });` !

Comment: got rid of the error message, but still now fading in the text

Comment: @ThomasBLund just download this example (click SAVE --> download button) http://jsbin.com/adefez/edit#javascript,html,live And take a look.

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to include the jquery library

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2) You need to wrap your code in a  `$(function()` or `jQuery(function($)`

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.fadeIn').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.before('<div>&nbsp;</div>');
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $this.prev().remove(); 
                $this.fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random()*1500)); 
            }, Math.floor(Math.random()*1500));
        }
    );​
});
```

Comment: or `jQuery(function($) {` to make sure `$` represents jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the update your code :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.fadeIn').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.before('<div>&nbsp;</div>');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.prev().remove();
            $this.fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
    });​
})
</script>
```

The

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

adds the jQuery library to your page - this enables you to use the jQuery functions. And you need to wrap your code in the

```
$(function() {

});
```

block so that it doesnt execute until the DOM is ready .. [See the docs here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: thanks, as you can see Im really new at this so .. I updated the code but still no cigar..
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.fadeIn').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.before('<div>&nbsp;</div>');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.prev().remove();
            $this.fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
    });​
})
</script>

Comment: you need to close the script tag like this : `<script src="jquery.....js"></script>` if you have what errors are you getting ?

Comment: Can you add your HTML to the question ? maybe an issue in there ?

Comment: <body>

<div class="fadeIn">Test 1</div>
<div class="fadeIn">Test 2</div>
<div class="fadeIn">Test 3</div>
<div class="fadeIn">Test 4</div>
<div class="fadeIn">Test 5</div>
<div class="fadeIn">Test 6</div>​

</body>

Comment: it seems that the JS is not able to grab and overrun the css
 <style>

.fadeIn{
   display: none; 
}​​
</style>

Comment: sorry.. style type="text/css">

.fadeIn{
   display: none; 
}​​
</style>

Answer (score 0):

Firstly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9YbR/1/) is the fiddle with your code working.

All you didn't do was import the jquery library in your head element.